# What's the difference between the unity7 and x11 plugs in snaps

Tags: snap

While snapping applications, I've seen some `snapcraft.yaml` files declaring either the `x11` and `unity7` plugs, or sometimes both.

What's their actual difference and when should I use which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/interfaces/ says:

---

#### unity7

Can access Unity7. Restricted because Unity 7 runs on X and requires access to various DBus services and this environment does not prevent eavesdropping or apps interfering with one another.

Usage: reserved Auto-Connect: yes

#### x11

Can access the X server. Restricted because X does not prevent eavesdropping or apps interfering with one another.

Usage: reserved Auto-Connect: yes

---

Looking at the code of the [x11 interface](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/interfaces/builtin/x11.go) and [unity7 interface](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/interfaces/builtin/unity7.go) things get even clearer. `x11` just gives you access to X, `unity7` gives you much more than that: access to icons, themes, pango, ibus, accessibility, accounts and much much more functionality on the Unity7 desktop (but other desktop environments too).